# ReactJS : update state regularly in a specific time interval

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I am creating a sensor app, where I have to update the state regular in a time interval of 15 seconds with the data receiving from the backend. Eventhough I can get the data successfully from the backend in the time interval, I cannot update the state in ReactJS. The code is as follows:

```
async regularCallAPI(){
    let result;
    const url = "http://..../...";
    await fetch(url).then( res =>  res.json()).then( res => { result = res});
    console.log("Regular Data from Backend : ", result);
    let updatedSensors = result.map( sensor => {
        return {
            floorNum: sensor.floor_no,
            roomNum: sensor.room_no,
            sensorStatus: sensor.sensor_status,
            alertStatus: sensor.alert_status,
            ownerName: sensor.owner_name,
            email: sensor.email,
            phoneNumber: sensor.phone_number,
            recordedDateAndTime: new Date(sensor.created_date).toLocaleString()
        }
    });
    await this.setState({ sensors: updatedSensors });
    console.log("sensor state updated ...");
}
```

and I have executed the above function in a interval of 15 seconds ;

```
timerId = setInterval(this.regularCallAPI, 15000);
```

The problem I have is, it runs the first time successfully and then when it run the second time, I get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState is not a function
```

and yes, the function is already binded to the component in the constructor. 
                   What is the reason for this behavior and what is the possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is made in a different context. You need to bind to this in order to have access inside the callback:

```
setInterval( () => this.regularCallAPI(), 15000);
```